# Regex to match a string exactly

Tags: java, regex, substring

I have the following string:

```
E:\Confluence_Attachments\ver003\10\85\1835010\124\165\4915874\19169322\1
```

How do I get the substring that begins with ver003?

I want only this part of the string:

```
ver003\10\85\1835010\124\165\4915874\19169322\1
```

Comment: Just add `.*` after `ver003`

Comment: This will do: `ver003\S*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you can use `.+` and group the desired elements with `()` and then use a `replaceAll` like

```
String s = "E:\\Confluence_Attachments\\ver003\\10\\85\\"
        + "1835010\\124\\165\\4915874\\19169322\\1";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll(".+(ver003.+)", "$1"));
```

Which outputs (as requested)

```
ver003\10\85\1835010\124\165\4915874\19169322\1
```